# How to properly sanitize (or parameterize) SQL Compressed Insert Statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, insert

**EDIT** Notice that the statement isn't a single insert. It inserts multiple value arrays using the `foreach` block.

```
StringBuilder sbSQL = 
  new StringBuilder(
    "INSERT INTO [table] ([fk_id], [Description], [Title] ) VALUES");

foreach(var item in items) {
    sbSQL.AppendFormat("({0},'{1}','{2}'),", 
      item.fk_id, item.description, item.title)
}

myDataContext.ExecuteCommand(sbSQL.Remove(sbSQL.Length - 1, 1).ToString());
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I really would like to use this method, as it sped up DB inserts 2 times. But I don't know how I am supposed to paramaterize it.

Comment: What is `myDataContext`? A LINQ-to-SQL context? Entity Framework context? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing a comment, but this was too long.

The parameterized queries in LINQ-to-SQL should do just fine for you. Something like this:

```
StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder(
       "INSERT INTO [table] ([fk_id], [Description], [Title] ) VALUES");

int paramNum = 0;
List<object> paramValues = new List<object>();

foreach(var item in items) 
{
    sbSQL.AppendFormat("({{{0}}},{{{1}}},{{{2}}}),", 
        paramNum, 
        paramNum + 1, 
        paramNum + 2);

    paramValues.Add(item.fk_id);
    paramValues.Add(item.description);
    paramValues.Add(item.title);

    paramNum += 3;
}

myDataContext.ExecuteCommand(
    sbSQL.Remove(sbSQL.Length - 1, 1).ToString(), 
    paramValues.ToArray());
```

The [`ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) function just takes your SQL command, complete with tokens (`{0}`) compatible with standard .NET string formatting functions, then turns the values you pass into parameters and uses its generated parameter names in place of the tokens. It's up to you to write the command and arrange the parameters however you like; it's not going to inspect or parse the command.

Comment: I didn't understand what you had meant before. I think this is the solution though!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [table value parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) (new to SQL Server 2008) - these allow you to pass all the values in one go.

The only issue is that these are not baked into Linq2SQL - so you need to provide your own method.

See [this](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/01/sql-2008-tvp-table-valued-parameters.html) blog post for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized queries.

```
public int ExecuteCommand(
    string command,
    params Object[] parameters
)
```

E.g.:

> ```
> List<string> myList = new List<string>();
>
> myList.Add("MyName");
> myList.Add("MyAddress");
>
> StringBuilder queryInsert = new StringBuilder();
> queryInsert.Append("insert into Customers(name, address) values ({0},{1})");
>
> this.myDataContext.ExecuteCommand(queryInsert.ToString(), myList.ToArray()); }
> ```

Comment: Notice that it isn't a single insert statement, it is many many inserts (usually around 12k). It wraps a foreach around the values array that gets appended to the insert.

Comment: Given that you're passing what appears to be a `string.Format`-compatible query to it (hence the `{0}`, `{1}`, etc.), I can't see how it would make any difference if you were to break it up into multiple sets of values. It looks like the context is just creating the command, the parameters, then passing the parameter names into `string.Format` (or something of that ilk) to format the command.

Comment: @Adam - multiple insert statements take longer than a single insert.

Comment: @Jeremy: I'm not saying that you should use multiple insert statements. A comment with my explanation was too long; see the answer I posted.