# Sql query to search database by date

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Can somebody advice me with the sql query to search ms database with specific date.

For example i want to search for all the transaction in day 13/02/2013.
In my database i have one column called Purchased Date which stores the date of purchase.

In database the date is stored in this format 16/02/2013 02:47:36 AM.

I want tom enter the date which i want in the text box and then pass that value to the query.

```
 public DataSet OrderByDate(DateTime date)
        {
            //  string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT  Customer.[Title] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Customer's Name] as CustomerName, Customer.[Customer's Ebayname], Customer.[Email Address], Customer.[Phone Number], Customer.[Address 1] + SPACE(2)  +Customer.[Address 2] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[City] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Post Code]+  SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Country] as Address, Customer.[Item Purchased], Customer.[Purchased Date], Customer.[Total Price] FROM Customer WHERE [Purchased Date]='" + date;
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0)
                return null;
            else
                return dataSet;
        }
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the `[Purchased Date]` column?

Comment: Get your C# code to produce this condition `WHERE [Purchased Date] >= '20130213' AND [Purchased Date] < DATEADD(day, 1, '20130213')`. Dates should be in `'YYYYMMDD'` format when passed to the database.

Comment: Have a look at this: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: And this: **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

Answer (score 4):

1. Always try to use the original/proper data type for your queries. In this case - datetime.
2. Never concatenate parameters into the SQL - especially strings, especially if the string is user input.

The below should work:

```
    public DataSet OrderByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        using(var oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                var cmd = oleConn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE [Purchased Date] BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd";
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[]
                    {
                        new OleDbParameter("dateStart", date.Date),
                        new OleDbParameter("dateEnd", date.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1))
                    }
                    );

                var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        return dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0 ? null : dataSet;
    }
```

I removed that long list of columns for clarity. 
As far as I understand, Oracle expects parameters with colon(:) in front of the parameter name as opposed to SQL Server's '@'. If the above doesn't work try with @ or maybe just use ? instead of parameter names and supply parameters without names.

The "using" part should handle closing the connection just fine even if an exception is thrown, and looks tidier than the finally section in your code.

Regarding this part:

```
                    new OleDbParameter("dateStart", date.Date),
                    new OleDbParameter("dateEnd", date.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1))
```

date.Date returns only the date part (time is 00:00:00) and date.Date.AddDays(1) is the next date (time is also 00:00:00) for example 2012-02-16 00:00:00 and 2012-02-17 00:00:00 - so exactly 24hrs- one day. You can subtract one tick if you like, but the idea is still the same. This way we are selecting all records where date falls in that range (hence using BETWEEN). You could try to achieve the same using Oracle datetime functions, but this is shorter/cleaner I believe.

Comment: but i am not comparing two dates, i am just looking for single date

Answer (score 1):

You can use it [**`LIKE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms179859.aspx) operator for your query;

```
string sql = "SELECT  Customer.[Title] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Customer's Name] as CustomerName, Customer.[Customer's Ebayname], Customer.[Email Address], Customer.[Phone Number], Customer.[Address 1] + SPACE(2)  +Customer.[Address 2] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[City] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Post Code]+  SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Country] as Address, Customer.[Item Purchased], Customer.[Purchased Date], Customer.[Total Price] FROM Customer WHERE [Purchased Date] LIKE '" + "'" + date "%'";
```

It gets as results all strings contains `13/02/2013` date like;

- 13/02/2013 02:47:36 AM.
- 13/02/2013 14:24:02 AM

etc..

And always use **[`parameterized sql`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)** in your queries. This kind of codes is always open for an [**`SQL Injection`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Like;

Comment: Do i have to pass the input from text box by converting to odatetime, Convert.ToDateTime(textbox1.text)

Comment: @ypercube Not compareing actually, for searching. It looks a good solution for me on this situation. Why do you think this can be a bad idea?

Comment: passing date as string and using like doesnot give any result//

Comment: @AmritSharma I'm not sure (since I can't try it now) but if you put as an input `13/02/2013`, this should work for this situation.

Comment: For a lot of reasons. Because with `LIKE '13/02/2013%'` the datetime column will be converted to string. So, no index can be used. The conversion to string is not guaranteed to be consistent as it will depend on SQL-Server settings. The date column may become `'2013-02-13 02:47:36 AM'` or `'2013-13-02 02:47:36 AM'` or `'20130213T02:47:36'` and the comparison will fail.

Comment: @AmritSharma Did you used like `"'" + date "%'"` ?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, you are right, but at this point, this doesn't look a big deal. Of course comparing with `BETWEEN` operator looks more logical. But using with `BETWEEN` also requires formatting.

Comment: using the query above, dataset is coming as null even though the date i have provided exist in database.

Comment: What is not a big deal? A query that doesn't return what is supposed to return is not a big deal?

Comment: +1 for parametrized queries suggestion. But don't use LIKE - this is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

when you want to eliminate the time component from your where clause, do this sort of thing:

```
where YourDateField >= @StartDate
and YourDateField < @TheDayAfterTheEndDate
```

Using the data from the question, @StartDate would be 2013-02-13 and @TheDayAfterTheEndDate would be 2013-02-14.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, to avoid any kind of "time" issues, I always use the `Date` property of date-time, both when I insert/update the database and when I read it out.  In fact, I wrote some wrapper code to do this automatically on columns where the time was not important.

This ensures that in the database, the time is always `00:00:00` both when inserting and updating.

So the query (avoiding any other SQL Injection/parameterised-query questions)

```
"SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _date = '" + date.Date + "'";
```

All things being equal and knowing that all insertions also used `.Date`, we can stop worrying about time.

Comment: Unless the time is actually important enough to store.

Comment: Or you are dealing with the existing database where the time part is already present.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use like, you can use a normal WHERE clause for this:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now.Date; //this will get you 2/16/2013 12:00:00am
        DateTime end = start.AddDays(1); //this will get you 2/17/2013 12:00:00am

        //make sure to parameterize your query like this
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE PurchasedDate >= @start AND PurchasedDAte < @end";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        using (conn)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter pmStart = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("start", start);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter pmEnd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("end", end);
            command.Parameters.Add(pmStart);
            command.Parameters.Add(pmEnd);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN library, you can use the *[DateTime.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)* to convert the datetime object to a string formatted in an unambiguous way:

```
string datestring = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); 
string sql = 
  " SELECT ... "
+ " FROM Customer "
+ " WHERE [Purchased Date] >= '" + datestring + "'" 
  + " AND [Purchased Date] < DATEADD(day, 1, '" + datestring + "')" ;
```

And I'm pretty sure there are better ways to pass the parameters to the query string than playing with quotes like this. See this question for example: **[How to properly sanitize (or parametrize) SQL Compressed Insert Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864227/how-to-properly-sanitize-or-parameterize-sql-compressed-insert-statement)**